# Copy table data from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, ssms

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with 7 tables. I want to copy the table data from this database to another database running on a SQL Server 2008 instance.

The tables will be exactly the same, I just need to copy the data from one to another.

Edit:

I get the following errors when trying to import from SQL Server 2008, I even check the box drop destination tables.:

> Validating (Error)
>   Messages
>   Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "AllowedHtmlSystemID".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 1 - DnnBBAllowedHtml" (79)" failed validation and returned validation
>   status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?  Do you want to move them programmatically, or just move them via SQL tools?

Comment: I get the following error: (see edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to insert data into an identity column. If you need the orginal identity values, first make sure they are not currently being used, then in the wizard, click the Edit Mapping button and check the Enable Identity Insert box. If you want to generate new ids, then in the destination in the mapping section, change the value to "ignore" for the identity field.

Comment: I would rather just copy the tables and restore them to the destination database.

Comment: yes but the identity will be broken once you remove it. If i just delete all the data from the destination tables, will i be able to do what you said?

Comment: You don't remove it from the table structure you temporarily disable during the data import. Deleting all teh existing data is a choice you have to make for yourself, It is generally a poor choice if you need the data or if it is a production system and a good choice if it was just test data on a development system. However, as long as you want the ids from teh other system, you don't need to delete existing data if they aren;t using the same ids already.

Comment: right clicking the table and going into design view is a night mare, i have like 14 tables.. not 7.. (my mistake) it also says i have to drop the tables and re-create then if i want to change the identity.

Comment: I didn't tell you go into design view. I told you to go to mappings while in the wizard to move the data. I do not want you to drop the identity I want you to temproarily disable it.  14 tables is nothing, I could do this task in under ten minutes, so it is hardly a nightmare.

Comment: In your question, show a screenshot of what you are looking at

Comment: Thanks for sticking by me. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the "Import data..." approach, you could also generate a sql script to insert the data into the other database.
Here's how to do it:
Right-click on the database and select **Tasks->Generate scripts...**

Select the specific tables that you'd like to copy (on the wizard page that lets you select the database objects)
When you get to the page that asks "Specify how scripts should be saved or published.":
-click the Advanced button
-For **Types of data to script**:  Change "Schema only" to "**Data only**"
Finish clicking through the wizard to generate your .sql file.

Then you can use the created .sql file to insert the data into your other database.  **NOTE:**  Be sure to change the **USE** statement to specify your destination database.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your sql2008 database in SSMS, then 'Tasks' - 'Import data...' and just follow the SSIS wizard.